# glRotatef not rotating as expected 

Tags: c++, opengl

I am trying to rotate a quad around its center, but when I run the app the quad rotates around the 0,0 position of the screen, I cant work out why, as everything looks fine to me. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(pxob->x, pxob->y, 0);

glRotatef(pxob->theta,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);

glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glColor3f((28.0f / 255.0f), (28.0f / 255.0f), (28.0f / 255.0f)); 

    glVertex3f(pxob->x - (SIZE / 2), pxob->y- (SIZE / 2), 0);
    glVertex3f(pxob->x + (SIZE / 2), pxob->y- (SIZE / 2), 0);
    glVertex3f(pxob->x + (SIZE / 2), pxob->y + (SIZE / 2), 0);
    glVertex3f(pxob->x- (SIZE / 2), pxob->y + (SIZE / 2), 0);
glEnd();
glPopMatrix();
```

**EDIT:**
Thank you Krom, for all your help and *guiding* me through it. I did have to call `glTranslatef` before `glRotatef` though as it wanted to still rotate around the 0,0 position. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `glRotatef` first, then `glTranslatef`.

This is because first object needs to be multiplied by rotation matrix (rotate object around its center), and then apply the translation matrix (move the rotated object to desired position).

If you do it the other way round the translated object will be rotated around 0;0 coordinates.

EDIT: Looking at your code - you build the quad with X/Y offset whereas you've already applied it to `glTranslatef`. Thats probably a mistake. The code should be:

```
glVertex3f(-SIZE / 2, -SIZE / 2, 0);
glVertex3f( SIZE / 2, -SIZE / 2, 0);
glVertex3f( SIZE / 2,  SIZE / 2, 0);
glVertex3f(-SIZE / 2,  SIZE / 2, 0);
```

Comment: Order of transformations is backwards order of matrix multiplication calls. So doing the rotation last is actually correct.

Comment: Both orders are correct, depending on result you want to achieve ;)

Comment: I changed the order as you said but still the same problem

Comment: hmmm, so would you say that what I have up there is fine?

Comment: I'm not sure if i'm doing it right, could you please display all 4 values: `glVertex3f(SIZE / 2, SIZE / 2, 0);`